# How to add content to PrintedPdfDocument

Tags: android, pdf

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument.html](http://PrintedPdfDocument)

I got it all except

```
// draw something on the page
 View content = getContentView();
 content.draw(page.getCanvas());
```

I want to generate pdf from data generated at runtime, NOT whats already on screen(view). 
eg I want to print numbers 1 2 3 4 5...n 
How can i do this?
How can i add table etc

please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `Canvas` drawing primitives (e.g., `drawLine()`, `drawText()`) to draw whatever you want.

Comment: Could you please guide me a little more. Canvas will be added to page which has all data. Will I be using content.draw(myCanvas); as such?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html#draw-content